# How do I add a dictionary as well as a list member to a key?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, dockerfile

I am building a docker file, a YAML file, and I have the following

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: test/php7.3
    ports:
     - "80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/home/app/src:cached
    container_name: 'phpapp'
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=<my-hostname>
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=phpapp.docker
```

The last two lines are the lines in question. As it currently is, it fails stating expected , but found '-'.

Answer (score 0):

Write your environment variable like this

```
    environment:
      - "XDEBUG_CONFIG=remote_host=<my-hostname>"
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=phpapp.docker
```

Comment: This is returning services.web.environment contains {"XDEBUG_CONFIG": "remote_host=my-hostname"}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string